# Circles and the continuum hypothesis

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

I was trying to understand the undecidable nature of the continuum hypothesis and came up with the following question:

The set of circles with a rational diameter is countably infinite (with cardinality equal to the cardinality of integers).
The set of circles with a rational circumference is countably infinite (with cardinality equal to the cardinality of integers).
The cardinality of the union of these sets is clearly smaller than the uncountable set of irrational numbers, but why isn't it larger than the set of countable integers?

Comment: Union of two countable is countable.

Comment: No, the union of two countable sets is also countable.

Comment: So the same could be said about the set of right triangles whose base and height are rational?

Comment: @user1688944 yes: there are countably many of those, too.

Comment: How is this related to the continuum hypothesis? And the cardinality of the union of circles is the same as the cardinality of irrational numbers, in fact cardinality of a single circle already is, and is larger than the cardinality of the set of integers.

Comment: To elaborate on that, why it is countable is because you can count then first rational diameter circle, then the first rational circumference circle, then the second rational diameter circle, and so on. This method will work for any finite union of countable sets.

Comment: No, the set of circles with a rational diameter is **not** countable. In fact, there are uncountably many circles with diameter one.

Comment: To extend what @bof said, there are continuum many circles with diameter $1$. So the cardinality of this set alone already equals to the cardinality of the irrational numbers.